The MAGE.EXE tool doesn't seam to return an error code. How to check if successful or not?
I have an addin for Outlook. The addin is created using a temporary manifest.
For the final release version. I have a build process where a manifest is finally signed using mage.exe -update.
But now I see that in case of an error, there is no retcode to the batch file.
How can I check if the EXE succeeded or failed? I can't even check the signature name with the -verify option. The verify option just tells me that there is a valid signature.

1.You could parse the output of the mage.exe command in your batch file to look for specific success or failure messages.
2.After running mage.exe -update, check if the signed manifest file exists in the expected location. If the file exists, it indicates that the signing process likely succeeded. 3.You can also try checking similar threads a and b if it helps you
